# How to remove "Remember me everywhere" option from Stripe checkout form

Tags: forms, checkout, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Payment processor on my site.

I have integrated the following form for Stripe Checkout.

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple

I want to remove the `"Remember me everywhere"` option from the form.

Answer (score 94):

You can disable the 'Remember me' checkbox now! Code varies slightly depending on your integration.

**Custom**:
`allowRememberMe: false`

**Simple**:
`data-allow-remember-me="false"`

More in our [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout)

Comment: This does not turn it off for someone who is already "remembered" from another site. If they input their email address it immediately texts them a code to put in place of their credit card details and then has a box that is also checked by default to "keep me logged in." None of this is easily known to the merchant usiing checkout and not easily figured out by the developer implementing it. I really wish I could remember where I asked stripe to "remember me" so I could get them to forget me.